# Get values from navigator.vibrate array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vibration

Is there a way to get the values from the `navigator.vibrate([]);` array? So that For example, I could calculate the total time in a function like this:

What I've tried is the regular dot notation: `navigator.vibrate[0]` for example

```
function my_vibration_function() {
  navigator.vibrate(
    [
      500,
      250, 
      100, 
      150, 
      100, 
      150, 
      500, 
      250, 
      500 
    ]
  );
}
```

Comment: I didn't find any mention in MDN or W3C about getting the current vibration state. So the answer is probably no.

Comment: navigate.vibrate() is a function, not an array.  You could make a pattern array before you call it...

Comment: @JimB., interesting. You mean that I make an array like say ````let vibrationPattern = [500, 250, 100,.. 250, 500]```` and then somehow insert that within the parenthesis of the function ````navigator.vibrate()````? Any suggestions on what material I need to read up on for that?

Comment: yes, it's that easy.  navigator.vibrate(vibrationPattern).

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of over-the-top solutions: :-)

```
class Vibrate {
    constructor(pattern) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
        this.startTime = Date.now();
        navigator.vibrate(pattern);
    }

    duration() {
        return this.pattern.reduce((t, x) => t + x);
    }

    remaining() {
        return Math.min(0, this.duration() - (Date.now() - this.startTime));
    }
}

let v = new Vibrate([
      500,
      250, 
      100, 
      150, 
      100, 
      150, 
      500, 
      250, 
      500 
    ]
  );
```